# Running Dotnet F Sharp Compiler from Command Line on Mac

Tags: .net, macos, f#

I am going through this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/fsharp-interactive/) but do not have fsc (F Sharp Compiler). Running
`dotnet fsc -a MyAssembly.fs` shows:

```
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-fsc does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

Running `ls /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100/FSharp` shows:

```
FSharp.Build.dll                          fsc.exe
FSharp.Compiler.Interactive.Settings.dll  fsc.runtimeconfig.json
FSharp.Compiler.Private.dll               fsi.deps.json
FSharp.Core.dll                           fsi.exe
Microsoft.FSharp.NetSdk.props             fsi.runtimeconfig.json
Microsoft.FSharp.NetSdk.targets           it
Microsoft.FSharp.Overrides.NetSdk.targets ja
Microsoft.FSharp.Targets                  ko
Microsoft.Portable.FSharp.Targets         pl
cs                                        pt-BR
de                                        ru
default.win32manifest                     tr
es                                        zh-Hans
fr                                        zh-Hant
fsc.deps.json
```

which has `fsi.exe` and `fsc.exe`. I would believe this would mean `dotnet fsc` would exist.

Additionally, I have mono from this [guide](https://fsharp.org/guides/mac-linux-cross-platform/) so `fsharpc`
 and `fsharpi` work.

Comment: Hi, can you please clarify your question?

Comment: How do I get `dotnet fsc` to run?

Answer (score 3):

The guide is a bit old. This [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56835885/how-to-directly-invoke-f-compiler-on-net-core) discusses that we usually don't directly use `fsc.exe` but rather create a project and use the .NET Core CLI (`dotnet`) to build and run F# projects. There is a getting started guide for [using the .NET Core SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/get-started/get-started-command-line) which should help you with that.

Regarding the usage of `dotnet fsc` there is a [discussion thread](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/4060) about it on GitHub. As far as I know the `fsc` keyword is - contrary to the things discussed - not implemented. The `fsi` keyword is, though. You can still use `fsc.exe` directly. Just call `dotnet <full-path-to-fsharp-sdk-location>/fsc.exe`. As mentioned above - there is usually no need to call `fsc` directly other than very special tasks or honest curiosity.